# document.write not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, lift

I am try to write inside html document.
this is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("Hello World!")</script>
```

I am working with chrome and get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'write'

I tried `alert` method and it worked.

EDIT: this is part of a project in scala/lift that also uses jquery if that may hint something. I suspect document object is redefined. is there a way to know that / to access the original one?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x32MK/ <what does that give you?

Comment: Are you sure you copied & pasted your code? It sounds like you have a typo on the word `document`.

Comment: it works in the same browser.

Comment: just copy/paste, I have jquery in the page, if there is any connection

Comment: Did you put this inside the body tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, trying to embed the google maps api in my lift application. The script also uses document.write to load external libraries. 
The Google Chrome console stated that there is no function document.write.

The problem seems to be that XHTML does not allow document.write. ( http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite )
A solution could be to change the mime/type of your documents, e.g. by adding the following line to your Boot.scala

LiftRules.useXhtmlMimeType = false

More solutions are described in the link below
http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Google-Maps-API-V2-amp-V3-Ajax-Loading-td1981862.html

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS code. I was doing the same, so what I did was make the JS file and shift the JS code there, meaning the ...

```
document.write("Printed by JavaScript.");
```

... part in `main.js` file. In `index.html` I just gave the path to my `main.js` file. It runs perfectly.

```
src = "main.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another variable called document?

Comment: how can i tell? maybe jquery has

Comment: looks like that might be the problem. is there a way to access the needed document?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.document.write("Hello World!")</script>
```

Comment: You should post some code at least. This is highly unusual behavior.

Comment: @Michael D. Irizarry It's not unusual at all. It's the [desired behavior for XHTML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite)

Comment: @CristianVrabie He did not post that he was using XHTML you just saw the right answer and commented, stop trolling.

Comment: @Michael D. Irizarry I'm not trolling. I was just trying to clarify. If people know that it is NOT unusual they might actually go and read why in XHTML they decided that document.write is bad. They do make some valid points.

Answer (score 0):

Just take your script tag in the bottom of the body , the problem will be solved,
I don't know why but it seems that when the script tag is in the head section it does this , despite using **deffer** attribute

Comment: From experience, the reason why this occurs is because when you put the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`, it will run before the body has loaded (And hence, before `document` becomes available). By inserting it at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, you are having it run when `document` is available.